# Do time-stopping items stop the difficulty from rising while active?

Tags: risk-of-rain

Do items in the game that stop time (Time Keeper's Secret, Unstable Watch, maybe more) actually stop "time"?

Meaning do they prevent the difficulty from rising while time is stopped? Or do they really just freeze all enemies/projectiles and call it "stopping time"?

It probably doesn't affect the game too much either way, since these items don't last more than a few seconds, but I was curious about it and couldn't find any information to confirm or deny it either way.

Answer (score 4):

**It does not stop the difficulty time, merely freezes enemies and projectiles**

It would have made more sense for them to call it freezing enemies, rather than stopping time.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do you know? Just personal experience or is this detailed somewhere?

Comment: This is from my personal experience playing the game. If you could use the Wiki, they might detail more information, but I do not believe so.

Comment: I checked the wiki but didn't see anything definitive. The thing is, I have played a lot and I tried to test this, but the difficulty rises so slowly and the "time stop" is so short that I really couldn't tell whether it was stopping or not.

Comment: I guess I would have to use a time stop item right when the difficulty is about to rise, and see it go up in the bar while time is "stopped". Have you seen this happen?

Comment: I did try it some time ago, because I had the same question, but it still went on. Maybe they fixed it in an update? What you should do is time how long the first difficulty jump takes place. Then, do the wait again, but like 1-2 seconds before, us the item and see if it still makes that jump, @CalvinScherle

Comment: Based on what you guys are saying: Sound very probable that it only stops enemies and not the difficulty timer.

Comment: The time only last a few seconds, so I wouldn't believe they would use that as a way of slowing time difficulty anyway.